# познакомиться as the answer of очень приятно

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения

Is it so informal to answer "**очень приятно**" with "**познакомиться**" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These phrases do not answer each other. When somebody is introduced or introducing themselves to you, you can answer:

> **Приятно познакомиться!**
>
> **Очень приятно!**
>
> **Очень рад!** (typical of men, I've never heard a lady to answer "Очень рада!" when sb is introduced to her)

It all has the same degree of formality, as you are saying it to an unknown person. Less formal will be not to say that at all, but you should be attentive to the society you are in to make sure it is concidered polite there and what people say instead. E.g., it can be "зд**о**рово, а я ... (the name)".

Comment: Thank you, Also could you let me know that can I use only познакомиться ? or I should say Приятно познакомиться! ?

Comment: No, we can not use this word separately in this meaning. You can say "очень приятно" or "приятно познакомиться".